# Descriptor bindings and binding numbers

Tags: vulkan

I'm a bit confused by the language used in the spec concerning the descriptor bindings described by the `VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding` struct. The *binding* element

> is the binding number of this entry and corresponds to a resource of the same binding number in the shader stages.

As stated in 14.5.3

> A variable identified with a **DescriptorSet** decoration of ***s*** and a **Binding** decoration of ***b*** indicates that this variable is associated with the `VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding` that has a *binding* equal to *b* in *pSetLayouts*[***s***] that was specified in `VkPipelineLayoutCreateInfo`

So if I get this correctly the descriptor bindings described by the `VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding` must have an entry for every active resource variable in that set. Which resource variable is referred to by each descriptor binding is dictated by the *binding* variable and the binding decoration of each variable.

So far so good. The confusing part is when calling `vkUpdateDescriptorSets`. Struct `VkWriteDescriptorSet` has element *dstBindng* which

> is the descriptor binding within that set.

I'm confused by whether *dstBindng*'s value must be the same with the binding number used as decoration in the variable resource, or it should be used as an index inside the `VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding` array.

Comment: You sound like you're confused as to whether two things with the same name refer to the same thing.

Comment: Well shouldn't they? I know that the correct answer is the first one (*dstBindng*'s value must be the same with the binding number used as decoration in the variable resource).

Probably I got stuck in my head that `VkWriteDescriptorSet`'s *dstBinding*  should refer to the elements of the `VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding` as an index.

Comment: The Vulkan specification is very carefully written to make it clear when it's talking about a binding in a descriptor set and an index of some user-provided array.

Comment: It is indeed and in the specific matter there is no reference that _dstBinding_ should be used as an index. Still I find it somewhat confusing.

Comment: Have a look at Intel's tutorial about [descriptor sets](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/api-without-secrets-introduction-to-vulkan-part-6). There You can find an explanation about bindings and I hope it is more clear than the specification.

Answer (score 2):

dstBinding within VkWriteDescriptorSet is the binding# of the first VkDescriptorBufferInfo pointed to by pBufferInfo.

i.e. i want to write 4 buffers to the descriptor set, but they are of different types (3 storage buffers and a uniform buffer). I can write the 3 storage buffers starting at binding #0 (writing to bindings #0, #1, #2) and then write 1 uniform buffer starting at binding #3.

```
VkDescriptorBufferInfo descriptorBufferInfo[4];
...

VkWriteDescriptorSet writeDescriptorSet = {};
writeDescriptorSet.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_WRITE_DESCRIPTOR_SET;
writeDescriptorSet.pNext = NULL;
writeDescriptorSet.dstSet = descriptorSet;
writeDescriptorSet.dstBinding = 0;
writeDescriptorSet.dstArrayElement = 0;
writeDescriptorSet.descriptorCount = 3;
writeDescriptorSet.descriptorType = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_STORAGE_BUFFER;
writeDescriptorSet.pImageInfo = NULL;
writeDescriptorSet.pBufferInfo = descriptorBufferInfo;
writeDescriptorSet.pTexelBufferView = NULL;

vkUpdateDescriptorSets(device, 1, &writeDescriptorSet, NULL, NULL);

writeDescriptorSet.dstBinding = 3;
writeDescriptorSet.descriptorCount = 1;
writeDescriptorSet.descriptorType = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER;
writeDescriptorSet.pBufferInfo = &descriptorBufferInfo[3];

vkUpdateDescriptorSets(device, 1, &writeDescriptorSet, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: i don't however know how writeDescriptorSet.dstArrayElement = 0; works but i speculate that i could have set it to 3 and skipped updating pBufferInfo to element 3